# NodeJs server issue with large file serving to multiple clients

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, html5-video

I have created video server application using NodeJs. I am able to serve all the static application files, upload videos as expected. But I am not able to watch same media file simultaneously on two different clients. It does not start playing a media in different browser until it stopped or paused on earlier client.
Issue occurs only when I try to play same file on different clients.

I tried using http server range requests, express, connect, vid-server modules.

I tried using nginx, lighthttp for the serving media file.

Could you please suggest me how to serve large(upto 1.5 gb) media files to multiple clients simultaneously.

Comment: Can you clarify _different clients_? Different computers, browser or different tabs?

Comment: I am trying on different tabs of crome browser on same computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using different tabs in Chrome/Chromium, beware that you cannot play the same video more than once ([1](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122557), [2](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31014)).

(This behaviour made me very confused once)

Instead test with different browsers, or even different computers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It worked on different computers, but as it is very big media file, in between its stops buffering. Could you please suggest best way to stream this media files for many clients ?